# Draw a rectangle which is partly behind another rectangle using Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have two separate questions. This is intended to be used with beamer, but I used standalone to make it more compact. So the command `\pause` has been commented but should be used.

First question: The blue rectangle, it would be nice to have the portion that intersects with the upper right rectangle behind it and invisible. I tried to fill the rectangle with white colour, but then the number is not seen.

Second question: the marking `(-,12)` which should be used together with `\pause` how can that be done so that the second time that it is written with `(-,12)^{*}` the star the first marking is deleted.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


                
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,
node distance = 20mm and 40mm, semithick]
 
\matrix(m) [matrix of math nodes, nodes in empty cells, nodes={minimum size=1cm, outer sep=0pt, text height=1.5ex, text depth=.25ex}]
{
 0      &    & 1        &      6  \\
        &    &          &         \\
\infty  &    & 0        &         \\
        &    &          &         \\
};

\draw (m-1-1.north west) rectangle (m-4-4.south east);

% Horizontal lines
\draw[-] (m-2-1.south west) -- (m-2-4.south east);
% Vertical lines
\draw[-] (m-1-2.north east) -- (m-4-2.south east);
% Box around upper right corner
\draw (m-1-4.south west) rectangle (m-1-4.north east);
% Blue marking
\node[draw=blue,rounded corners = 1ex,fit=(m-1-3)(m-2-4),inner sep = -5pt] {};

\node at (3,1) {$(-,12)$};
\node at (1,-2.5) {$(1,6)$};
% I intend to use this with beamer \pause
\node at (3,1) {$(-,12)^{*}$};



\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: While your code is ok with `standalone`, I could not run it with a `beamer` class, embedding the `tikzpicture` inside a `frame` environment.  Could you please re-post it in a correct `beamer` format ?

Comment: You can add `fill=white, fill opacity=0.8` options for the "Blue marking" in case you'd like to go with a semi-transparent rectangle.  Or you can add two nodes with `\node at (m-1-3) {1}; \node at (m-1-4) {6};` (rather than writing on the matrix) to make it visible on top of the filled-in blue rectangle.

Comment: For the overlay stuff, one way is to use overlay specifications on the drawing commands,  so `\node<1> ...` for the first one and `\node<2-> ...` for the second.  Or have a single node with overlay instructions inside it. I'd use `(-,12)^{\visible<2->{*}}` so that the reveal doesn't make it move.

Comment: I'm not clear on _which_ rectangle should be visible on the overlap.  Do you want to see the full blue rectangle or the full black rectangle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this at all something that helps you (it is not exactly true to your initial code):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,fit}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    \frame{\frametitle{title}
    \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[x=20mm,y=20mm]
            \draw<2->[thick,blue,rounded corners=10pt] (1.1,1.1) rectangle (1.9,1.9);
            \draw[step=20mm,thick] (0,0) grid (2,2);
            \draw[thick,fill=white] (1.5,1.5) rectangle (2,2);
            \node[rectangle,minimum size=10mm,anchor=north east] at (2,2) {6};
            \begin{scope}[every node/.style={anchor=north west},xshift=2.5mm,yshift=-2.5mm]
                \node at (0,1) {$\infty$};
                \node at (0,2) {0};
                \node at (1,1) {0};
                \node at (1,2) {1};
            \end{scope}
            \node[anchor=north] at (1.5,0) {$(1,6)$};
            \node[anchor=west] at (2,1.5) {$(-,12)\onslide<2>{^\star}$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks a lot, I will adapt my code to your solution.

Comment: That's great. Feel free to "accept" my answer in that case. Also, note that I edited it a bit, I realised you can save an entire line of code in the last `node`.

Comment: I would use `visible` rather than `onslide` as I believe (though I haven't tested it) that with `onslide` the node will change location and lead to a possible jump when the slide changes.

Comment: I checked for that and the behaviour you describe is that of `\only<>{}`. `onslide` accounts for the shift, so there are no jumping figures.